# Do Windows 10 reset most basic environment variables if lost?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, environment-variables, path

We have all seen the story of the person deleting their path variable and not being able to use their computer like they used to.
But the path variable is really something that can be fixed and altered often manually according to what directories the user or the programs they use need to access.

What about hardware related variables though? i.e. Processor related variables.

Do Windows 10 refresh those variables to their normal values if for some reason they get lost or altered wrongly? Is there a self healing mechanism in place?

Comment: Why not try it out for yourself? Document one of the variables,  change it and see what happens. Then you can come back here and answer your own question.

Answer (score -1):

I was asking this question because I would install a new processor on a new motherboard and wanted to be sure that the processor related system variables would change as well accordingly. Turns out that **yes, this happens automatically on the next boot.**